# Suppress building bibliography with Latexmk

Tags: bibliographies, latexmk

Latexmk apparently forces bibliography build even when no `\bibliography` command is present.

How does one suppress building bibliography?

When building the `main.tex` without the `\bibliography` command, I get this:

```
------------
Running 'bibtex  "main"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'bibtex main'...
For rule 'bibtex main', running '&run_bibtex(  )' ...
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: ch-copyright.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

I am using VS Code for building the pdf.

Comment: As far as I know it does not do this. Can you provide a minimal example that trigger a compilation like this

Comment: Latexmk only runs bibtex if the document inputs or tries to input a bbl file, since bbl files are made by bibtex. If the document doesn't use a bbl file, then latexmk doesn't invoke bibtex.  So I strongly suspect that your document inputs a bbl file.  If it does but you don't want to use bibtex, then invoke latexmk with the -nobibtex option.